# Как исправить передвижение QGraphicsPixmapItem при использовании Drag&Drop

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-n-drop, qgraphicsview, qgraphicspixmapitem

При передвижении `PixmapItem` объект передвигается по координатам внутри себя.
Как можно переопределить функции, чтобы он двигался относительно сцены?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QEasingCurve, QFileInfo, QLineF, QMimeData,
                          QParallelAnimationGroup, QPoint, QPointF, QPropertyAnimation, qrand,
                          QRectF, qsrand, Qt, QTime)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QDrag, QImage, QPainter, QPen,
                         QPixmap, QTransform)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsPixmapItem,
                             QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView)

class PixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    n = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('hold.png'))
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        drag = QDrag(event.widget())
        mime = QMimeData()
        drag.setMimeData(mime)
        pos = event.pos()
        self.moveBy(pos.x(), pos.y())

        drag.exec_()
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        print('enter')

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, e):
        print('leave')

import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene()
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
pixmapItem = PixmapItem()
scene.addItem(pixmapItem)
view.setScene(scene)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`
Элемент поддерживает интерактивное перемещение с помощью мыши. 
Нажимая на элемент, а затем перетаскивая элемент, он перемещается вместе с курсором мыши.
Если у предмета есть дети, все дети также перемещаются.
Если элемент является частью выбора, все выбранные элементы также перемещаются.
Эта функция предоставляется в качестве удобства благодаря базовой реализации 
обработчиков событий мыши QGraphicsItem.

```
import sys                             
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *                         

class PixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'))
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)

    pixmapItem = PixmapItem()
    pixmapItem.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)     # <<<=====

    scene.addItem(pixmapItem)
    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте пример приведенный ниже. Он демонстрирует не только перемещение изображения,
а также предоставляет возможность масштабирования изображения.

Нажмите клавиатуру: `Key_Right` - для увеличения, `Key_Left` - для уменьшения масштаба.
Я думаю, что вам должно понравиться.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QStandardPaths, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QColor, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL  import QGLFormat
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QFileDialog, 
                             QGraphicsItem, QApplication, QPushButton)

class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    # Цвет фона
    backgroundColor = QColor(28, 31, 34)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(800, 600)
        # Установите цвет фона
        self.setBackgroundBrush(self.backgroundColor)
        # Кэширование фона
        self.setCacheMode(self.CacheBackground)

        # QGraphicsView визуализирует сцену, вызывая render(). 
        # По умолчанию элементы рисуются в окне просмотра, используя обычный QPainter 
        # и используя подсказки рендеринга по умолчанию. 
        # Чтобы изменить подсказки рендеринга по умолчанию, которые QGraphicsView 
        # передает QPainter при рисовании элементов, вы можете вызвать setRenderHints().
        # Эти подсказки используются для инициализации QPainter перед каждым видимым элементом. 
        # QPainter использует подсказки рендеринга для переключения функций рендеринга, 
        # таких как сглаживание и плавное преобразование pixmap.

        self.setRenderHints(
            QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.TextAntialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        # Класс QGLFormat указывает формат отображения контекста рендеринга OpenGL
        # hasOpenGL()Возвращает true, если оконная система поддерживает OpenGL; 
        #            иначе возвращает false.
        if QGLFormat.hasOpenGL():
            self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)

        # Попробуйте найти лучший режим обновления, проанализировав области, 
        # которые нужно перерисовать
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(self.SmartViewportUpdate)
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(-400, -300, 800, 600, self)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        # изображение
        self._itemImage = None

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие обработки кнопок """
        self._scaleImage(event)
        super(GraphicsView, self).keyReleaseEvent(event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """ Очистите все элементы в сцене, когда окно `закрыто` """
        self._scene.clear()
        self._itemImage = None
        super(GraphicsView, self).closeEvent(event)

    def _scaleImage(self, event):
        """ Операция масштабирования изображения """
        if not self._itemImage:
            return
        scale = self._itemImage.scale()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:              
            # Увеличить
            if scale >= 0.91:
                return
            self._itemImage.setScale(scale + 0.1)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:            
            # Уменьшить  
            if scale <= 0.11:
                return
            self._itemImage.setScale(scale - 0.1)

    def loadImage(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Пожалуйста, выберите изображение', 
            ".",
            'Image(*.jpg *.png)')
        if not path:
            return
        if self._itemImage:
            # Удалить предыдущий элемент
            self._scene.removeItem(self._itemImage)
            del self._itemImage
        self._itemImage = self._scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(path))
        self._itemImage.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self._itemImage.setScale(0.1)         # Коэффициент загрузки по умолчанию

        size = self._itemImage.pixmap().size()
        # Отрегулируйте изображение посередине
        self._itemImage.setPos(
            -size.width()  * self._itemImage.scale() / 2,
            -size.height() * self._itemImage.scale() / 2
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = GraphicsView()
    w.show()
    ww = QPushButton('Выберите файл', clicked=w.loadImage)
    ww.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, проблема в том что мне нужно событие которое срабатывает когда я нажимаю мышкой вне QGraphicsPixmapItem, а за него как раз отвечает dragLeaveEvent и я просто хотел чтобы сам item хорошо передвигался относительно QScene

Comment: @Daniil я добавил еще один пример, по-моему это то, что вы хотели.

Comment: нет это не то, вы мне скидываете примеры как двигать QGraphicsItem через setFlag, а мне надо через Drag&Drop

Comment: @Daniil посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780915/drag-n-drop-inside-qgraphicsview-doesnt-work-pyqt